# Difference between touches and targetTouches

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, dom-events, mobile-safari

I am trying to learn mobile web app development and going through ;
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touch.html

I wanted to understand the difference between touches and targetTouches... Not in a literal sense (like I do understand targetTouches is specific to an element)

I wanted to understand more from a syntax perspective... like when we say targetTouches inside any function, what exactly are we referring to... Any example would be really great..

Answer (score 21):

**touches**: A list of information for every finger currently touching the screen.

**targetTouches**: Like touches, but is filtered to only the information for finger touches that started out within the same node.

[More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056026/variation-of-e-touches-e-targettouches-and-e-changedtouches)