# How do i get touch id in javascript from touchstart

Tags: javascript, touchscreen

touchsrat returns 3 arrays - targetTouches, chnagedTouches and touches. How do i figure out which touch triggered the event? I need the id so that i can track chnges from touchmove event

[Variation of e.touches, e.targetTouches and e.changedTouches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056026/variation-of-e-touches-e-targettouches-and-e-changedtouches)

This is somewhat helpful but i don't understand what is "node" - DOM element to which i bind the event?