# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageX' of undefined

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, touchstart

I am tinkering with `touchevents` in js. I have encountered this error in my logcat in eclipse.

```
document.getElementById("squareBracket").
    addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, false);
document.getElementById("squareBracket").
    addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, false);

function touchHandler(e) {
 if (e.type == "touchstart") {
 alert("You touched the screen!");
  } else if (e.type == "touchmove") {
 // alert(e.changedTouches[0].pageX);
 // alert(e.changedTouches[0].pageY);
 } else if (e.type == "touchend" || e.type == "touchcancel") {
  alert('X :' + e.targetTouches[0].pageX); 
  alert('Y :' + e.targetTouches[0].pageY);
}
}
```

If I remove the comment in the `if` in `touchmove`, the coordinates popup. However, if it is commented, the error in my logcat appears.

Comment: First of all, the comments don't influence your logcat error. it seems e.targetTouches[0] is null or undefined. be aware it's `changedTouches` in first case and `targetTouches` in second case.

Comment: so I should change it to `changedtouches`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should start understanding the difference of targetTouches, changedTouches and touches here: [Variation of e.touches, e.targetTouches and e.changedTouches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056026/variation-of-e-touches-e-targettouches-and-e-changedtouches)

in your case in the moment of touchend or touchcancel the targetTouches list is empty and the information remains in changedTouches.

changing your code to:

```
alert('X :' + e.changedTouches[0].pageX); 
alert('Y :' + e.changedTouches[0].pageY);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: so I can save the start coordinates at `changedTouches[0]` and the end coordinates in `changedtouches[1]` ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes but you should always check if there are items available in your list of touches with if (e.changedTouches[0] && e.changedTouches[1]) { ... } just to make sure that there have been 2 touches.

Comment: hey Dennis I added this code `if (e.type == "touchmove") {
   startX = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
   startY = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;
  } else if (e.type == "touchend" || e.type == "touchcancel") {
   endX = e.changedTouches[0].pageX; 
   endY = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;
   alert (startX + endX);
  }` 

It only shows the end coordinates, why is that?

Comment: You need to store your start coordinates in the touchstart event and use this stored coordinates + the changedTouches coordinates inside your touchend event. You need to track this yourself, javascript can't do this natively for you